# Xorg 11.10 kernel 3.0.0-16-generic running Extremely High CPU memory. Was a bug Introduced in recent update?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, xorg

So any luck with this yet?
I am running Kubuntu 11.10 x86_64 kernel 3.0.0-16-generic
i7 @ 3.8GHz 24GB Ram NVIDIA gtx 260 running the 290.10 Drivers

This actually didn't start happening until I updated the Kernel
However it is the same effect, /usr/bin/X is running way over 575M<-Virt 450M<-Res ~80% CPU almost constantly. My machine is lagging hardcore. I used to be able to run multiple vm's hundreds of tabs on chrome etc.. and now I can barely use my system.

I've got the performance settings in xorg.conf

```
    |       |--> Device "Device0"
    |       |       |--> Driver "nvidia"
    |       |       |--> VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    |       |       |--> BoardName "GeForce GTX 260"
    |       |       |--> Option "UseEvents" "On"
    |       |       |--> Option "Coolbits" "1"
    |       |       |--> Option "RenderAccel" "O"
```

I haven't changed anything as far as programs I am running, and since this bug was introduced in the last big update I was wondering if there was a known issue that i could track, or if anyone has any suggestions on how to track down the offender that is causing Xorg to run like this?

Comment: does the problem go away if you boot using an older kernel (press shift on boot to display your Grub)?

Comment: @fossfreedom
I haven't tried an older kernel, I have come to a better understanding however. I believe this has something to do with chrome and chrome-dev. This did start happening after the kernel update last week and a large amount of other packages were updated as well.
I have been watching my processes since my last reboot, after modifying the xorg.conf, what i posted above actually includes my recent modification, I just dumped it after I had made the change and before I booted I posted the above. RenderAccel was added I believe this works in conjunction with UseEvents to stabilize.

Comment: I also haven't run chrome-dev but I've been watching my processes for the past 5 hours and memory is still being eaten up at a rather steady pace. So I have implemented 
`sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
in order to bring it down once it gets up to about 19GB and it reduces it down to 8 incredibly So something has gone awry in some program I am using. I am going to have to either methodically kill programs to find the leak or wait till another update :D when I have time and whether or not the next update fixes it shall be a coin toss

Comment: OK So I updated to the next kernel 3.0.0-16.28 generic and I'm having no more issues, I think this has to do with the Intel fix I saw in the changelog

Comment: excellent news - please can you expand and add your comment as an answer - you can accept it... and we can vote on it as well.  Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the kernel to the next revision fixed the problem.

A couple days after this post there was a new release to the kernel and I believe that was *3.0.0-16.28* in the update log I saw there was a fix for Intel processors so I believe this fixed the issue.

On a side note I would recommend to all to add the *Xorg.conf* modifications I added in an attempt to fix the CPU load problem:

```
Option "UseEvents" "On"
Option "RenderAccel" "O"
```

This has made my setup run even snappier if you can believe it. :D